# How to filter through a table?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am trying to filter through a sapui5 table defined by xml. I know you can filter through a sapui5 table defined by javascript by using `getBinding()` but it doesn't work when trying to filter through a sapui5 table defined by xml. Is there a way to use `getBinding` when defining a table using xml or a similar way to filter through a table?

Here is my [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/cejuzi/edit?html,output) when using javascript to define the table. The filtering for this table works.

Here is my [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/nejaje/edit?html,output) when using xml to define the table. The filtering for this table does not work. Why? How can I get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address a control it is useful to assign an identifier:

```
<table:Table width="100%" id="players" visibleRowCount="15".../>
```

In your filter function you do the following:

```
oView.byId("players").getBinding("rows").filter(allFilter);
```

It is not working in your example as you do not have a reference to the table compared to the JS case where you create the table instance in your coding. Thus you need to lookup the control.